# Test if captured groups succeeded in Regular Expression in C#.NET

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to to validate video link URLs. In particular, validate share link URLs versus embed video src URLs. My current regular expression looks like this to validate two different types of video URL from vimeo.com:

```
^(?i)(http[s]?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?(?'gp1'player\.)vimeo\.com\/(?(k'gp1')video\/|())(?((\w)+\/?$
```

I'm trying to use the same regex to validate the following URLs (the links below are bogus so do not click on them ):

- http://www.vimeo.com/123FEDSE
- http://player.vimeo.com/video/123FEDSE

I can't seem to get the regex working for both cases and would like one regex to test both cases if possible.

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:
Thanks dtb for the post. It seems though that the regex still passes if the user passes in an invalid url: 
for example, if user accidentally supplied http://player.vimeo.com/123FEDSE instead of the valid http://player.vimeo.com/video/123FEDSE, it would pass the regex validation. I'm trying to use the regex to validate the URL's to ensure that it's of proper format.

Is there a way to check if a previous capture group exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [Free Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/) it will help you to change your regex pattern and test it with a custom data on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Check

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern); 

    if(match.Success) { 
       //do something 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Regex language is a bit different from the language your regex is written in.

Here is a close approximation:

```
string url1 = "http://www.vimeo.com/123FEDSE";
string url2 = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/123FEDSE";

string pattern = @"^(https?://)?(www\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com/(video/)?(\w)+/?$";

bool result1 = Regex.IsMatch(url1, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
bool result2 = Regex.IsMatch(url2, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^http://[^<>'"]*?vimeo.com/[^"'<>]*?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(http[s]?://)?(w{3}\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com/(video/)?(\w)+/?$
```